# Apple 2 network connection says Selected Appletalk Connection can't be found

Tags: network, ethernet

Apple ii is setup for ethernet with addon card. Link light is green, however I cannot ping google. It's setup for 10 Base T and used to connect just fine. I powered cycled my modem one day, and after a snowstorm it would no longer connect. I can access my default internal network fine, just not anything external. Also, other nodes work fine on the network, just not the Apple ii.

Comment: Is it a 2e or 2c?

Comment: It's a IIe, 10 Base T

Comment: Not sure how we can help with you external internet problems. Do you have access to the modems settings page from your computer?

Comment: @Buscar웃 It's not a problem with the external internet, it's a problem with the Apple IIe. All other devices work fine on the network.

Comment: That was not clear to me in your question.

Comment: @Buscar웃 absolutely, I updated it.

Comment: @BigHomie You may get better results for issues with legacy Apple products by registering and posting at the [Applefritter](http://www.applefritter.com/forum/84) dedicated Apple II forum.